# Deployed One laravel app on AWS Elastic Beanstalk & EKS Same Database RDS Why getting fast Response in Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, containers, devops, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-eks

Deployed One laravel app on AWS Elastic Beanstalk & EKS Cluster Using Same Database 
RDS 
Why I am getting fast Response in Elastic Beanstalk while in EKS there delay of 3.02 ms.

there not much data in database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue of network. it was network between EKS & RDS so taking too much time to load the whole website.

For elastic beanstalks connection with RDS is from outside and speedy so site loading time was less over there.